# Named query not found

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb

I use EJB 3 and I'm trying to get a simple string from database but I receive this message

> Named query not found: SELECT tr FROM Travauxdereseauurbain tr

and I don't really get what this means.

Here is the entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Travauxdereseauurbain")
public class Traveauxdereseauurbain implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="idtru")
private int idtru;
@Column(name ="article")
private String article;
@Column (name="designationtraveau")
private String designationtraveau;
@Column(name="unite")
private String unite;
@Column(name="prixHTVA")
private float prixHTVA;
@Column(name="prixTTC")
private float prixTTC;
@Column (name="qtt")
private float qtt;
@Column(name="montantHTVA")
private float montantHTVA;
@Column(name="montantTTC")
private float montantTTC;


///GETTERS, SETTERS AND CONSTRUCTOR   
}
```

and the DAO class

```
@Stateless
public class TravauxdereseauurbainDAO {     

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;       

    public Traveauxdereseauurbain affichernimpr()
    {


      Query q =em.createNamedQuery("SELECT tr FROM Travauxdereseauurbain tr");

      return  (Traveauxdereseauurbain) q.getResultList().get(0);
    }
}
```

and finally the error message is:

> Servlet.service()" pour la servlet Faces Servlet a généré une exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Named query not found: SELECT tr FROM Travauxdereseauurbain tr

Thans you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling the right method. You need to call [em.createQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: i used em.createQuery and the error message became                       " Travauxdereseauurbain is not mapped [SELECT tr FROM Travauxdereseauurbain tr]"

Comment: That's because in HQL you have to use class names instead of table names. Your class is called `Traveauxdereseauurbain`, while your mapped table is called `Travauxdereseauurbain`. Watch for typos!

Answer (score 0):

You are using createNamedQuery to retrieve the pre-compiled HQL to do the query. 
you can put your query's name and query's content on your domain object, like this

```
@NamedQuery(name = "aName", query="aHql")
public class Traveauxdereseauurbain implements Serializable {
```

then in your dao

```
em.createNamedQuery("aName);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your query returns a list of object

```
 public List<Traveauxdereseauurbain> affichernimpr() {       
            Query query = em.createNamedQuery(""SELECT tr FROM Travauxdereseauurbain tr");
            return (List<Traveauxdereseauurbain>) query.getResultList();
```

Comment: This variant is still not OK. `em.createNamedQuery` does a lookup by name through the set of predefined queries. So your query will lead to the same error, unless there is a named query named "SELECT tr FROM Travauxdereseauurbain tr" :))